# Querying a variable using the ACS census API

Tags: request, census, tiger-census

I'm looking here, which says this variable exists in the ACS1 2016 collection:

- https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1/profile/variables/DP02_0001E.json

And is listed generally in the [data dictionary](https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1/profile/variables.html) for that collection.

But I query it in any of the formats [listed here as examples](https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1/examples.html), it does not:

- https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1?get=DP02_0001E&for=zip%20code%20tabulation%20area:60601
- https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1?get=group(DP02)&for=zip%20code%20tabulation%20area:60601
- https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1?get=DP02_0001E&for=state:01

All return:

```
error: error: unknown variable 'DP02_0001E'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same problem and I think I understand the solution thanks to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hrecht/censusapi/issues/46).

- URLS with the piece `acs/acs1` will work for the DETAILED TABLES.
- You are looking to pull information from a DATA PROFILE, thus you must use URLs with the path `acs/acs1/profile`.
- If you were looking for a SUBJECT TABLE variable it would be `acs/acs1/subject`.

I believe the appropriate paths can generally constructed from the "dataset name" column in the table [here](https://api.census.gov/data.html).
For example, the following should work:

```
https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1/profile?get=DP02_0001E&for=state:01
```

NB: For geographic queries, you should also note that you need to use one of [the available geographies](https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1/profile/geography.html) and you may need to provide the high-level geography, e.g.:

```
https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1/profile?get=DP02_0001E&for=county:031&in=state:17
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent a long time banging my head against the wall with the API until I found your post